# pandas, pyreadstat: not able to read .DTA file

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I'm trying to read a `.DTA` file with pandas and pyreadstat and get following errors.

```
df = pd.read_stata('test.DTA')  
>>ValueError: Version of given Stata file is 48. pandas supports importing versions 105, 108, 111 (Stata 7SE), 113 (Stata 8/9), 114 (Stata 10/11), 115 (Stata 12), 117 (Stata 13), 118 (Stata 14/15/16),and 119 (Stata 15/16, over 32,767 variables

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_dta('test.DTA')
>>pyreadstat._readstat_parser.ReadstatError: This version of the file format is not supported
```

Comment: Your `.dta` file was saved by a really old version of Stata. The file format was very different then. Based only on the error message you show I do not think there is an implementation in `pandas`/`pyreadstat` to read such an old version. Newer versions of Stata can read `.dta` files saved by older versions of Stata. Are you able to open the file in a newer version of Stata, save it again, and then try to import it using `pd.read_stata()`?

Comment: Is there a way to do that programmatically? I have a large amout of `.dta` files which need to be exported. Reading the files as text results in one concatenated line.

Comment: In Stata yes. Stata is a software with a programming language. But I assume you do not have access to Stata and given that the tools you already mention can't handle a file this old, I am not sure if there are tools outside Stata that can.

Comment: The best solution in R that is also open source is `haven` (https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/read_dta.html) but it only reads versions back to 113.

Comment: 48 is so old I am inclined to think that is not correct. Since you have multiple files, can you test other files and see if all of them are version 48? File format 105 was released in  year 2000.

Comment: I get this error for every file that I try to read.